# Excel: transforming an indexed sheet with many columns to two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have an excel sheet with rows like this:

```
Fruit     | Apple  | Banana | Grape | Peach
Vegetable | Cabbage| Lettuce| Carrot|
```

and would like a two column output duplicating the index (first column):

```
Fruit     | Apple
Fruit     | Banana
Fruit     | Grape
Fruit     | Peach
Vegetable | Cabbage
Vegetable | Lettuce
Vegetable | Carrot
```

Simplicity of use is more important than efficiency as the data is small and the users are inexperienced. Thank you

Comment: Is there a program that is generating output in the above said format ? If the data set is small, have you tried copy paste & [transpose](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12366/convert-a-row-to-a-column-in-excel-the-easy-way/) function in excel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have this in *Sheet1*:

[image]

and run this short macro:

```
Sub ReOrganize()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim N As Long, M As Long, i As Long, j As Long, K As Long
    Dim t1 As String, t2 As String
    N = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 1

    For i = 1 To N
        t1 = sh1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        M = sh1.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For j = 2 To M
            sh2.Cells(K, 1).Value = t1
            sh2.Cells(K, 2).Value = sh1.Cells(i, j)
            K = K + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

We will get this in *Sheet2*:

[image]